# Does Pennsylvania have a mature minor doctrine?

Tags: united-states, pennsylvania, minor, medical

I'm not trying to get medical care, I'm just curious. I was wondering if the state of Pennsylvania had what is known as a "Mature Minor Doctrine"  which, if I understand correctly, would allow minors, in a limited set of circumstances, to consent to medical treatment in lieu of their parents if said minor could demonstrate a level of knowledge and maturity necessary to make such decision. I know that some other states have this statute in their medical codes, and it varies from state to state what the implementation of this law. If PA does have such a doctrine, what are its specifics (age, how maturity is determined, etc.) And if it falls under PA emancipation law (which to my knowledge is horrendously complected.)

Answer (score 2):

PA is a state that has discussed the mature minor doctrine in *Commonwealth v. Nixon*, 61 A.2d 1151 (Pa. 2000), however, as you mention, the results are complicated.

The following is not well-cited, but it should give you a lay of the land:

[Journal of Lancaster General Hospital (2009)](http://www.jlgh.org/Past-Issues/Volume-4---Issue-2/Medico-Legal-Matters.aspx)

You don't mention a particular area of medicine, but the mature minor doctrine is frequently associated with the controversy on underage reproductive behavior.  So let me treat that briefly.  The statute governing abortion is [18 Pa.C.S. § 3206](http://www.legis.state.pa.us/cfdocs/legis/LI/consCheck.cfm?txtType=HTM&ttl=18&div=0&chpt=32), which is about a quarter of the way down the link.  The courts are beginning to get involved as well, and a recent "judicial bypass" case that dealt with parental consent is *re Jane Doe*, J-108-2010 (Pa. 2011).